# AN ILS Software exported file couldn't open and error said XML sheet content problem

Tags: xml

error097760_01.xml
Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\Fast\Desktop\list of CyberSecurity books in print.xlsx'

Removed Part: /xl/sharedStrings.xml part with XML error. (Strings) Illegal xml character. Line 2, column 42544.


Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Try to open an export file of ILS Software "Insignia". expecting the best solution

Comment: Use an online XML checker to see the error.  XLSX is NOT XML.   Do not try to open an XLSX file with an XML library.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! May you improve your question with a better formating please ? See: [Editing Help]( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)